# JAXB equivelent of @Mappedsuperclass

Tags: jaxb

Take for example the two classes below, how can I tell JAXB to render the id field of BaseEntity as an attribute of Person ?

```
@MappedSuperclass
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlAttribute
    private Date createdDate;

    // Getters & setters

}
```

.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SuperHero extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    // Getters & setters

}
```

Desired output :

```
<SuperHero id="XYZ" createdDate="today">
    <Name>Superman</Name>
</SuperHero>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, one should remove the `@XmlRootElement` annotation from BaseEntity.